# Can't Find ndiswrapper GUI

Tags: wireless

I'm very new to Ubuntu so please bear with me. I installed Ndiswrapper(Windows Wireless Drivers) in Ubuntu Software Center but when i tried to search the app in my dash nothing show up.

I already search through the net and tried different steps but nothing works. I tried to reinstall it but still nothing happens.

can someone here shed some light on me please.

Comment: by the way i'm using ubuntu 14.10

Comment: ndis-gtk is the graphical interface of ndiswrapper.

Comment: yeah i installed it in the ubuntu software center but i cant open the gui..when i search on the dash nothing shows... i already installed it before and i can locate the gui but now its none... what could i be doing wrong here?

Comment: @xangua, not "ndis-gtk" but "ndisgtk".

Answer (score 1):

I find it when I put 'Wireless' as a search item in the dash. If it is still not found, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo ndisgtk
```

Of course, you may install Windows wireless drivers entirely from the command line. We'll be happy to assist you.

Comment: how to mark this thread as solved?